# We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, addtocart

When click **add to cart button** in product details page I'm getting this error

> "We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now."

Can you please anyone help me.

Comment: Check error log, What is says ?!!

Comment: Nothing display in error log

Comment: @venkataprasad check this https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Error-when-quot-Add-to-Cart-quot-Error-message-quot-We-can-t-add/td-p/49961

Answer (score 0):

Please Go to admin panel or Marketing Tab -> Cart Price Rules  remove all price rule Then clear cache working fine

Thanks